# Different results in AES encryption between Python and Java

Tags: python, java, android, aes, cbc-mode

I am trying to encrypt the communications between a java and a python app and the problem is I'm getting different result in decrypting the encrypted string from the other side in both apps.
I searched a lot but I didn't found any problem in the code and I will be much appreciated if you guide me in this.
Here is the encryption function in java side:

```
public static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        String privateKey = "1234567887654321";
        String stringIV = getRandomIV();
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(stringIV.getBytes());
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(privateKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

        String encryptedString = new String(encrypted)
        String toEncrypt = stringIV + encryptedString;
        return android.util.Base64.encodeToString(toEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


static String getRandomIV() {
    UUID randomUUID = UUID.randomUUID();
    return randomUUID.toString().replaceAll("_", "").replaceAll("-", "").substring(0,16);
}
```

and here is the decryption part in python:

```
msg_bytes=bytes(msg, encoding="utf8").decode("utf-8",'ignore')
b64decoded=base64.b64decode(msg_bytes)
cipher = AES.new('1234567887654321'.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, b64decoded[0:16])
decoded = cipher.decrypt(b64decoded[16:48])
decoded = bytes(decoded).decode("utf-8",'ignore')
```

I'm testing this with a 32 byte message and I'm getting different results with AES part, alse here is my java decryption function:

```
public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {
        String privateKey = "1234567887654321";
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        byte[] base64decoded = new byte[0];
        base64decoded = android.util.Base64.decode(encrypted, android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);
        String base64decodedString = new String(base64decoded);
        byte[] byteiv = Arrays.copyOfRange(base64decoded, 0, 16);
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(byteiv);
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(privateKey.getBytes(), "AES");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);
        byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(hex(base64decodedString.substring(16,48).getBytes()).toCharArray());
        byte[] original = new byte[0];
        byte[] bytemsg = Arrays.copyOfRange(base64decoded, 16, base64decoded.length);
        original = cipher.doFinal(bytemsg);
        return new String(original.toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

and also python's encryption:

```
data = str(json.dumps(data))
iv = Random.get_random_bytes(16)
cipher = AES.new('1234567887654321'.encode("utf8"), AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
byte_iv = bytearray(iv)
encrypted = bytearray(cipher.encrypt(self.pad(data).encode("utf8")))
data = base64.b64encode(bytes(byte_iv + encrypted))
data = list(data)
data = bytes(data)
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: `getRandomIV()` is missing.

Comment: @Topaco sorry, I just edited and added 'getRandomIV'

Comment: The Java code itself cannot work, because the ciphertext is hex encoded during encryption (`encryptedString`), but not hex decoded during decryption (`bytemsg`). Furthermore there are design issues concerning the generation of the random IV and the concatenation of IV and ciphertext. There are many examples for both on SO. These complicate porting, thus focus on fixing and refactoring the Java code first before porting.

Comment: Furthermore your code on Java side mixes up String and byte[]. Concating two strings and then call `getBytes("UTF-8")` does not always have the same result as converting both substrings to bytes and then concat them. When dealing with encrypted data always use `byte[]` variables, never String (unless the data has been hex or base64 encoded). BTW: why so complicated generation of IV? Just use `byte[] iv = new byte[16]; new SecureRandom().nextBytes(iv);`.

Comment: @Robert Thank you Robert I really appreciate your comment, the concatenating was the problem and thank you for suggesting this way for generating IV, I have little experience with Java, If you post this as answer I can approve that cause it fixed my problem.

Comment: @Topaco thank you so much yes the hex encoding was a mistake and I removed it but besides that convertng to strings and then concatenating was also a wrong thing to do, I really appreciate your help and suggestions.